# wrong path found of mysql in xampp server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

As I start XAMPP server it gives me following status:

```
21:19:49  [mysql]   MySQL Service detected with wrong path
21:19:49  [mysql]   Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
21:19:49  [mysql]   Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
21:19:49  [mysql]   Found Path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL >>>Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL >>>Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL
21:19:49  [mysql]   Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe >>--defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
```

Well, I deleted that MySQL Server 5.1. I restarted the XAMPP server but still it is giving me the same error.

What should I do to make it right?

Comment: This probably belongs on [sf]

Comment: What kind of XAMPP are you using portable?